# Webkit is blocking my ability to tack on classNames in scss

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, webkit

This works:

```
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 1.4rem;
  height: 1.4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: $havenAccent;
  cursor: pointer;
  &.--disabled {
    background: gray;
  }
}
```

This does not work:

```
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 1.4rem;
  height: 1.4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: $havenAccent;
  cursor: pointer;
  &.--disabled {
    background: gray;
  }
}
```

When I scroll over '--disabled' on both examples I am shown '.slider --disabled'.
I want to be able to change the background color of the example that has the '.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb'

Answer (score 0):

What about using:

```
.slider { 
  &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 1.4rem;
    height: 1.4rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: $havenAccent;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  &.--disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background: gray;
  }
}
```

I moved the `.slider` class up one level so that both `::-webkit-slider-thumb` pseudo-element and the class `.---disabled` can use it, and as `::-webkit-slider-thumb` it must be repeated.

This will output the following css:

```css
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 1.4rem;
  height: 1.4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #someColor;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider.--disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: gray;
}
```

Comment: edited* Nothing changed. The element that I want to turn gray is still $havenAccent.

Comment: No luck what? that's not helpful

Comment: adding a ```&.--className``` just adds a space to the classnames. this becomes className = 'slider --disabled'

Comment: @helper12345 what are you wanting it to output? why doesn't this help?

Comment: The slider, when active, is a light blue, when disabled I want it to be gray. For whatever reason the added classname --disabled isnt being appended when ```::-webkit-slider-thumb``` is involved.   ``` .--disabled``` works with the rest of my css. it's so strange. I used your code, which makes perfect sense, but it still did not work.

Comment: It's because Safari requires `::-webkit-slider-thumb` to come last

Comment: ahh I see, so it is overwriting my disabled, interesting

Comment: not necessarily overwriting. Your attempt outputs `.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb.--disabled` which isn't valid to select the webkit slider thumb pseudo element (what a mouthful)

Comment: makes sense. How would you recommend I append the class then?

Comment: Updated answer works, bravo. I upvoted your answer. Thank you so much

Comment: @helper12345 no problem, please accept it when you feel ready to